# Hadoop: Reduce is not producing the desired output, it is same as map output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Here is my `Map`

```
 public static class MapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            String[] fields = value.toString().split(",", -20);
            String country = fields[4];
            String numClaims = fields[8];
            if (numClaims.length() > 0 && !numClaims.startsWith("\"")) {
                context.write(new Text(country), new Text(numClaims + ",1"));
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is my `Reduce`

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            double sum = 0.0;
            int count = 0;

            while (values.hasNext()) {
                String[] fields = values.next().toString().split(",");
                sum += Double.parseDouble(fields[0]);
                count += Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
            }

            context.write(new Text(key), new DoubleWritable(sum/count));
        }
```

Here is how it is configured

```
Job job = new Job(getConf());

            job.setJarByClass(AverageByAttributeUsingCombiner.class);
            job.setJobName("AverageByAttributeUsingCombiner");

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    //        job.setCombinerClass(Combinber.class);
            job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

            job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    //        job.setNumReduceTasks(0); // to not run the reducer
            boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
            return success ? 0 : 1;
```

The Input is of form

```
   "PATENT","GYEAR","GDATE","APPYEAR","COUNTRY","POSTATE","ASSIGNEE","ASSCODE","CLAIMS","NCLASS","CAT","SUBCAT","CMADE","CRECEIVE","RATIOCIT","GENERAL","ORIGINAL","FWDAPLAG","BCKGTLAG","SELFCTUB","SELFCTLB","SECDUPBD│                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    ","SECDLWBD"                                                                                                                                                                                                         │                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    3070801,1963,1096,,"BE","",,1,,269,6,69,,1,,0,,,,,,,                                                                                                                                                                 │                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    3070802,1963,1096,,"US","TX",,1,,2,6,63,,0,,,,,,,,,                                                                                                                                                                  │                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    3070803,1963,1096,,"US","IL",,1,,2,6,63,,9,,0.3704,,,,,,,                                                                                                                                                            │                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    3070804,1963,1096,,"US","OH",,1,,2,6,63,,3,,0.6667,,,,,,,
```

The output of the entire `map reduce` looks like

"AR"    5,1                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
"AR"    9,1                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
"AR"    2,1                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
"AR"    15,1                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
"AR"    13,1                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
"AR"    1,1                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
"AR"    34,1                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
"AR"    12,1                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
"AR"    8,1                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
"AR"    7,1                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
"AR"    23,1                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
"AR"    3,1                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
"AR"    4,1                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
"AR"    4,1

How can I debug and fix this issue? I am learning hadoop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as already mentioned, is that you're not overriding the default reduce method of the default abstract Reducer class.

More concretely, (one/the) problem up to this point is that your reduce method signature is:

```
 public void reduce(Text key, **Iterator**<Text> values, Context context) 
             throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

and, instead, it should be:

```
 public void reduce(Text key, **Iterable**<Text> values, Context context) 
             throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

The old-API version is correct, you implement the Reducer interface `reduce()` method and it works.

A good verification for this kind of situations is to use `@Override` because it forces compile time checks of signature mismatches.

Comment: this technique is of great help

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer is not "catching". There is likely a type mismatch or something like that, so your `reduce` function is not matching up with the abstract interface it is inheriting from... so it's not overriding. By default, `reduce` will use the `IdentityReducer`, which does nothing (which is what you are experiencing).

To be sure that you are actually overriding, add `@override`:

```
@override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, Context context)
```

This will throw an error because the function signature doesn't match. This hopefully will help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: this technique is of great help

Answer (score 1):

- I am currently using `hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar` and tried to wrote the `Map Reduce` with the new API, not sure why it didn't work
- This program is part of [Hadoop in Action code](http://manning.com/lam/HadoopinAction_source_code.zip) and I am learning hadoop with this book.
- When I ran the same `map reduce` program with `old API syntax`, it works absolutely fine.
- The code looks like (along with Combiner included, I was testing it before Combiner first)

> ```
> import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
> import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
> import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
> import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
> import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
> import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
> import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
> import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
> import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
>
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.util.Iterator;
>
>
> public class AveragingWithCombiner extends Configured implements Tool {
>
>     public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase
>             implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
>
>         static enum ClaimsCounters { MISSING, QUOTED };
>
>         public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
>                         OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
>                         Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
>
>             String fields[] = value.toString().split(",", -20);
>             String country = fields[4];
>             String numClaims = fields[8];
>
>             if (numClaims.length() > 0 && !numClaims.startsWith("\"")) {
>                 output.collect(new Text(country), new Text(numClaims + ",1"));
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static class Combine extends MapReduceBase
>             implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
>
>         public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
>                            OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
>                            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
>
>             double sum = 0;
>             int count = 0;
>             while (values.hasNext()) {
>                 String fields[] = values.next().toString().split(",");
>                 sum += Double.parseDouble(fields[0]);
>                 count += Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
>             }
>             output.collect(key, new Text(sum + "," + count));
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase
>             implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {
>
>         public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
>                            OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output,
>                            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
>
>             double sum = 0;
>             int count = 0;
>             while (values.hasNext()) {
>                 String fields[] = values.next().toString().split(",");
>                 sum += Double.parseDouble(fields[0]);
>                 count += Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
>             }
>             output.collect(key, new DoubleWritable(sum/count));
>         }
>     }
>
>     public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
>         // Configuration processed by ToolRunner
>         Configuration conf = getConf();
>
>         // Create a JobConf using the processed conf
>         JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, AveragingWithCombiner.class);
>
>         // Process custom command-line options
>         Path in = new Path(args[0]);
>         Path out = new Path(args[1]);
>         FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
>         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
>
>         // Specify various job-specific parameters
>         job.setJobName("AveragingWithCombiner");
>         job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
>         job.setCombinerClass(Combine.class);
>         job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
>
>         job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
>         job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
>         job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
>         job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
>
>         // Submit the job, then poll for progress until the job is complete
>         JobClient.runJob(job);
>
>         return 0;
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>         // Let ToolRunner handle generic command-line options
>         int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new AveragingWithCombiner(), args);
>
>         System.exit(res);
>     }
> }
> ```